# Attempt to get length of null array - retrieve bitmap image from sqlite DB

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to retrieve an image from an SQLite database. The image is stored as a BLOB and trying to retrieve it using an array. I'm not sure why its doing this. The permissions are all set correctly.

```
package com.example.joao_.quizathonegroupteamproject.Activity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.joao_.quizathonegroupteamproject.DatabaseClasses.User;
import com.example.joao_.quizathonegroupteamproject.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Quoc Nguyen on 13-Dec-16.
 */

public class UserListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private  int layout;
    private ArrayList<User> foodsList;

    public UserListAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<User> foodsList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.foodsList = foodsList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return foodsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return foodsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View row = view;
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        if(row == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(layout, null);


            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgFood);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        User food = foodsList.get(position);

        byte[] tblUsersImage = food.getImage();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(tblUsersImage, 0, tblUsersImage.length);
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: `"I'm not sure why its doing this."` What is it doing, are you getting a specific error message?

Comment: How do you save and read bitmap to/from the DB?

Comment: Your array are ever null?

Comment: your  food.getImage()` returns null

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve BLOB image and stored it in Byte array like this:

```
byte[] array = cursor.getBlob(columnIndex);  

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(array, 0 ,array.length);
```

and then set it into image view

```
holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't provide your SQLite database class but i think , your `food.getImage();` return null value .

check  dataInsert method OR getData in your SQLite db !